# Where are situated all SharePoint server error codes descriptions?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

During execution the code belowe `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException` with `ServerErrorCode = -2147024894` has been thrown. But I don't know any information about this code. May be you know where I can find the correspondence between SP ServerErrorCodes and their descriptions ?

```
private SP.Folder GetFolderByRelativeUrl(string folderRelativePath)
{
    var folder = _spClientContext.SpContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderRelativePath);
    _spClientContext.SpContext.Load(folder);
    _spClientContext.SpContext.ExecuteQuery(); // here exception is thrown
    return folder;
}
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee545394.aspx) has no information about codes' descriptions.

---

UPDATED:

Full description

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: File Not Found.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
   ...
```

Comment: What is the *full* exception, ie the result of calling `Exception.ToString()` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've updated the post

Comment: I think that answers the question. You don't need the code when you already have the exception's reason. BTW that is *NOT* the full exception. Full means all of it, because the text includes *inner* exceptions and properties that could be used to differentiate the different errors

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `InnerException` is null. No it isn't. I need info about server errors codes descriptions.

Comment: If you want to differentiate server errors, this code won't help.It's *not* a Sharepoint code, it's a Windows error ([HRESULT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT) specifically). An exception may or may not be related to an HR code. This one specifically is 0x80070002, a generic "File Not Found" error. The values are defined in various SDK headers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Finally, I've found [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd930252%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, by chance I've found.

[SharePoint server erros codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd930252%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: It isn't exactly what you expect. If you check, it's the HResult from the System.IO.FileNotFoundException. If the server throws a *different* exception, you may get a different code or none at all.Eg what happens if you don't have permissions for that specific folder? Or the error is thrown by a custom field or solution?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In this case I only need to check if folder exists or not. So if server returns exception with error code as I've written before than folder doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Many common error codes are included in the `ClientErrorCodes` class:

CSOM: [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientErrorCodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee544356(v=office.15))

JSOM: [SP.ClientErrorCodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff410286(v=office.14))